# COUNTAX function will not return output if I set the filter criteria to a calculation within the Power BI workbook

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that will display the number of times a specific price occurs within the price column. The specific price comes from a measure that is calculating the optimal price. When I set the filter equal to the optimal price calculation, it just returns blank.

In this particular example, the measure that gives me the optimal price is saying that the optimal price should be $1.00. So if I manually input 1.00 into the filter section, my output comes back correctly. Why doesn't this work when I set my filter to the optimal price calculation which is the exact same value as me manually entering 1.00?

Again, this calculation works just fine if I change the price filter to Table_Name'[Price] = 1 instead of putting it equal to the Optimal Price Calculation.

```
Optimal_Price_Count =
COUNTAX (
    FILTER (
        'Table_Name',
        'Table_Name'[Price] = [Optimal Price Calculation]
            && 'Table_Name'[Product] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'First Product'[Product] )
    ),
    'Table_Name'[Price]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[Optimal Price Calculation]` measure is calculated within the FILTER function, which means there is a [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) that turns row context into filter context for the measure.

I'd recommend defining this as a variable and then referencing it. You can do the same for the product too if you like:

```
Optimal_Price_Count =
VAR OptimalPrice = [Optimal Price Calculation]
VAR SelectedProduct = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'First Product'[Product] )
RETURN
    COUNTAX (
        FILTER (
            'Table_Name',
            'Table_Name'[Price] = OptimalPrice
                && 'Table_Name'[Product] = SelectedProduct
        ),
        'Table_Name'[Price]
    )
```